# Highcharts with data from table, how to add custom marker for specific value from specific series?

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I have a highcharts line chart with the data source being an HTML table.

I want to add a custom marker for a specific marker on a specific series to indicate a break even point.

My highcharts js:

```
    $(function () {
        var chart = new Highcharts.Chart({
          colors: ["#cc1c0d", "#1d63af" , "#9eb215"],
          chart: {
          type: 'line',
          backgroundColor:'rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.85)',
          renderTo: 'container'
         },
         data: {
              table: 'sheet6'
          },
          title: {
              text: 'Cost Comparison'
          },
          xAxis: {
              tickInterval:3,
              title: {
                  text: 'M'
              },
          },
          plotOptions: {
                series: {
                    marker: {
                        symbol: 'circle',
                        radius: 3,
                        fillColor: '#FFFFFF',
                        lineWidth: 2,
                        lineColor: null // inherit from series
                },
                    shadow: true
                }
            },
          yAxis: {
              allowDecimals: false,
              title: {
                  text: 'Cost'
              },
              labels: {
                    formatter: function () {
                        return Highcharts.numberFormat(this.value,0);
                    }
                }
          },
          credits: {
              enabled: false
          },
          tooltip: {
              headerFormat: '<b>{series.name}</b><br>',
              pointFormat: 'Month {point.x}: {point.y} kUSD'
          },

      });
  });
```

And here is a sample of the data in the table:

```
<table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" id="sheet6" class="sheet6 gridlines">
        <col class="col0">
        <col class="col1">
        <col class="col2">
        <col class="col3">
        <tbody>
          <tr class="row0">
            <td class="column0 style119 s">M</td>
            <td class="column1 style117 f">M</td>
            <td class="column2 style117 f">A</td>
            <td class="column3 style117 f">Profit/Loss</td>
          </tr>
          <tr class="row1">
            <td class="column0 style0 n">0</td>
            <td class="column1 style118 f">0</td>
            <td class="column2 style118 f">0</td>
            <td class="column3 style118 f">0</td>
          </tr>
          <tr class="row2">
            <td class="column0 style0 n">1</td>
            <td class="column1 style118 f">119</td>
            <td class="column2 style118 f">551</td>
            <td class="column3 style118 f">-432</td>
          </tr>
          <tr class="row3">
            <td class="column0 style0 n">2</td>
            <td class="column1 style118 f">238</td>
            <td class="column2 style118 f">717</td>
            <td class="column3 style118 f">-479</td>
          </tr>
          <tr class="row4">
            <td class="column0 style0 n">3</td>
            <td class="column1 style118 f">357</td>
            <td class="column2 style118 f">860</td>
            <td class="column3 style118 f">-504</td>
          </tr>
          <tr class="row5">
            <td class="column0 style0 n">4</td>
            <td class="column1 style118 f">476</td>
            <td class="column2 style118 f">980</td>
            <td class="column3 style118 f">-504</td>
          </tr>
          <tr class="row6">
            <td class="column0 style0 n">5</td>
            <td class="column1 style118 f">595</td>
            <td class="column2 style118 f">991</td>
            <td class="column3 style118 f">-396</td>
          </tr>
          <tr class="row7">
            <td class="column0 style0 n">6</td>
            <td class="column1 style118 f">713</td>
            <td class="column2 style118 f">1002</td>
            <td class="column3 style118 f">-288</td>
          </tr>
          <tr class="row8">
            <td class="column0 style0 n">7</td>
            <td class="column1 style118 f">832</td>
            <td class="column2 style118 f">1012</td>
            <td class="column3 style118 f">-180</td>
          </tr>
          <tr class="row9">
            <td class="column0 style0 n">8</td>
            <td class="column1 style118 f">951</td>
            <td class="column2 style118 f">1023</td>
            <td class="column3 style118 f">-72</td>
          </tr>
          <tr class="row10">
            <td class="column0 style0 n">9</td>
            <td class="column1 style118 f">1070</td>
            <td class="column2 style118 f">1034</td>
            <td class="column3 style118 f">37</td>
          </tr>
          <tr class="row11">
            <td class="column0 style0 n">10</td>
            <td class="column1 style118 f">1189</td>
            <td class="column2 style118 f">1044</td>
            <td class="column3 style118 f">145</td>
          </tr>
          <tr class="row12">
            <td class="column0 style0 n">11</td>
            <td class="column1 style118 f">1308</td>
            <td class="column2 style118 f">1055</td>
            <td class="column3 style118 f">253</td>
          </tr>
          <tr class="row13">
            <td class="column0 style0 n">12</td>
            <td class="column1 style118 f">1427</td>
            <td class="column2 style118 f">1066</td>
            <td class="column3 style118 f">361</td>
          </tr>
          <tr class="row14">
            <td class="column0 style0 n">13</td>
            <td class="column1 style118 f">1546</td>
            <td class="column2 style118 f">1077</td>
            <td class="column3 style118 f">469</td>
          </tr>
          <tr class="row15">
            <td class="column0 style0 n">14</td>
            <td class="column1 style118 f">1665</td>
            <td class="column2 style118 f">1087</td>
            <td class="column3 style118 f">578</td>
          </tr>
          <tr class="row16">
            <td class="column0 style0 n">15</td>
            <td class="column1 style118 f">1784</td>
            <td class="column2 style118 f">1098</td>
            <td class="column3 style118 f">686</td>
          </tr>
          <tr class="row17">
            <td class="column0 style0 n">16</td>
            <td class="column1 style118 f">1903</td>
            <td class="column2 style118 f">1109</td>
            <td class="column3 style118 f">794</td>
          </tr>
          <tr class="row18">
            <td class="column0 style0 n">17</td>
            <td class="column1 style118 f">2022</td>
            <td class="column2 style118 f">1119</td>
            <td class="column3 style118 f">902</td>
          </tr>
          <tr class="row19">
            <td class="column0 style0 n">18</td>
            <td class="column1 style118 f">2140</td>
            <td class="column2 style118 f">1130</td>
            <td class="column3 style118 f">1010</td>
          </tr>
          <tr class="row20">
            <td class="column0 style0 n">19</td>
            <td class="column1 style118 f">2259</td>
            <td class="column2 style118 f">1141</td>
            <td class="column3 style118 f">1119</td>
          </tr>
          <tr class="row21">
            <td class="column0 style0 n">20</td>
            <td class="column1 style118 f">2378</td>
            <td class="column2 style118 f">1152</td>
            <td class="column3 style118 f">1227</td>
          </tr>
<tr><td></td></tr>        </tbody>
    </table>
```

I have seen a number of examples to add a custom marker, but my JS differs from them and so I am unsure where to add the custom marker in the code.

All the examples that I have seen have had their data embedded in the highcharts js. But my data comes from a table.

**Update 1:**

I have created a fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/partisanentity/n5gaf26o/

If you look at the blue series (Automated) it begins to intersect with the red series (Manual) at month 8. I want to add a custom marker to the blue series at month 8.

The indication for the break even (intersection) will not come from the table. It will come from a different part of my code that uses PHP.

All I need to know is where in my example do I need to add this and how?

Comment: have you tried the way suggested in the examples you saw? It should work the same, once data (defined in config object or html table) is loaded to highcharts, it can be treated as if it were defined in the series options.

Comment: @RahulSharma yes I have. But since my example differs completely from the layout of the examples I saw I do not know if I entered the styling parameters in correctly, or whether I entered them into the correct area.

Comment: can you create a fiddle?

Comment: Where in your data are you specifying that custom marker should be used? Should custom marker be set in case data is spcific? If yes, then adding a function that will additionaly parse your data - add marker info per point - in the data's [complete function](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#data.complete) in chart's options. If no, then info about marker should be in data, yet still parsing your data and setting marker settings will resolve the issue. Please post a live example, e.g. in JSFiddle, if you will have further problems with implementing.

Comment: @KacperMadej I have added a fiddle, and also an  update to my original question. Basically all I need to know is where in my highcharts js code do I need to add a custom marker and how? Once I know this I can insert the month dynamically.

Comment: Marker options can be set per point, e.g. when point is given as object - example: https://jsfiddle.net/25ed2gb3/

Comment: @KacperMadej that's great thank you. Please post as an answer so I can select it.

Comment: You are welcome :) Posted

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Parsing your data in the [data's complete](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#data.complete) function in chart's options and setting marker settings should resolve the issue.

Marker options can be set per point, e.g. when point is given as object - example: jsfiddle.net/25ed2gb3